# Pass the array in multiple selected table cell into next view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I tried to pass array to next view controller from my table view..

here is my code this far.

```
 @IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pilihtabel") as! labelpilih
        for index in 0 ... (tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count)! - 1{
        let selectedrow = tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?[index].row
        print(pilihan[(tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?[index].row)!])
        view.pilih = pilihan[selectedrow!]

    }

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

it works , but only pass the last row i picked.

Comment: For pass multiple records in tableview multiple selection allows = true. and then select multiple selection data to your next view controller .

Comment: @AlbertWu hey what's the pilihan in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `view.pilih = pilihan[selectedrow!]` you are assigning the value `pilihan[selectedrow!` to your next view's `pilih` variable.

But the `pilih` is not of array type so at the end of the loop the last value is overwritten to it and hence it only contains the last value.

To solve this you should make it array type and should append the values like

`view.pilih.append(pilihan[selectedrow!])`

Comment: thank you, it's work perfectly. Can you explain a little bit about **append** ? how can i miss that

Comment: @AlbertWu you needed to pass some values from pilihan (and not the single value) hence the next view's pilih variable must be an array type so you can to add those values in the pilih variable, therefore "append" is used to add those values one by one.

Comment: when i tried to change my pilih in next view's to Array type. it shows "",array1,array2.  this is how i declare pilih to array type 'var pilih : Array = [""]'

Comment: you should change that line to var pilih = Array(), this will initialise the variable without any element.

Comment: okay thank you so much. I am really a newbie, and must learn a lot . i will keep in mind about that "append" btw.

Comment: hi @Aakash wht's the pilihan in this case?

Comment: @deltami it is a randomly named array variable

Comment: @Aakash thanks mate but its not working in my case :( . hey will you try to solve my question?

Comment: @deltami sure what is it?

Comment: @Aakash   hey sorry for replying late see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892379/how-to-apply-filter-based-on-multiple-selected-rows-in-uitableview-using-swift-3   problem is same want to pass all the selected values to the next view controller on button click but scenario is different.

Answer (score 3):

Another Way to pass it

```
@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pilihtabel") as! labelpilih

        let arrPassing = NSMutableArray()
        for index in 0 ... (tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count)! - 1{
            let selectedrow = tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?[index].row
            arrPassing.addObject(pilihan[selectedrow!])
            print(pilihan[(tabelpilihan.indexPathsForSelectedRows?[index].row)!])

        }
        view.pilih = arrPassing
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

Comment: what is the different between NSMutableArray and Array or NSArray?

Comment: @AlbertWu In objective C NSArray is used to define an array which cannot be altered/changed later while NSMutableArray is used to define an array which can be altered/changed later on

Comment: @AlbertWu since in swift constants are defined used let and variables by var hence Array type variable will be of mutable type if it is defined using var and immutable if define using let