# how to get selected text of textfield on button click? pickerview is set as an inputview to the textfield. Swift

Tags: swift3, uibutton, uitextfield, uipickerview

**currently my output is  displaying selected values from pickerview inside textfields.**

[image: Pickerview as an inputview to textfield]

now my question is i want to access all these values on submit button and want to display in another view controller how to do this?. let me explain my scenario my first vc is set as collectionview from one of the collectionviewcell m redirecting to this page.

Note: i already know that how to pass data between two view controller. but its not working in my case.Please Help.

**Code**

```
@IBAction func StaffAtten_Action(_ sender: Any) {


//        let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StaffAttendence_SecondPage") as! StaffAttendence_SecondPage
//
//        secondVC.a = active_text.text!
 //        secondVC.b = active_text.text!
 //        secondVC.c = active_text.text!
//            secondVC.savedata.append(year.text!)
//        secondVC.savedata.append(month.text!)
//        secondVC.savedata.append(institute.text!)
}
}
```

Comment: Does the `text` property not work?

Comment: please show your code that you are using for navigation or passing data and its not working for  you

Comment: @Sweeper please refer my updated question

Comment: @NishantBhindi have updated my question with code.

Comment: You said you know how to pass data from one VC to another, but judging from the commented part of the code, you don't seem to. Are you presenting the new VC with a segue or something else?

Comment: @Sweeper yes have already push using navigation controller too.

Comment: So you connected the button with the other VC in the storyboard?

Comment: @Sweeper  yes sir i connected the button with secondvc.

Comment: @Sweeper i also tried by appending all the values in one array and passed it to second vc. now m stucked :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are instantiating a brand new VC and passing data to it. The VC that is actually presented is not the one you created.

Since you have a segue connecting the two VCs, override `prepare(for:sender:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? StaffAttendence_SecondPage {
        vc.a = ...
        vc.b = ...
        // pass the rest of the data here...
    }
}
```

Comment: @deltami No, put this outside the submit button

Comment: but want to pass all these values on button click. :(

Comment: @deltami Yes, the data will be passed when you press that button. The button's IBAction method is not the only place to execute stuff you want to happen on button press. Try it out!

Comment: vc.a = ? cant access the values.

Comment: @deltami Shouldn't it be one of `year.text!`, `month.text!` and `institute.text!`? You should be able to access them.

Comment: sir will you please try to look into this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892379/how-to-apply-filter-based-on-multiple-selected-rows-in-uitableview-using-swift-3